# ArcPy Network Analyst solve function, shows 'ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed.'

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst, arcgis-license-manager, error-000824

I want to find the shortest path between two points. I first make a route layer from an analysis network and then add two point locations.
While python shows the following errors when I use the solve function. Can anyone tell me the reason?
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed.
Failed to execute (Solve).

Code works when I use Python window in ArcMap and I actually have all ArcGIS licenses

codes:
'''

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\hyan1\Desktop\try\network\network_for_wageningen.mdb"
network = r'C:\Users\hyan1\Desktop\try\network\network_for_wageningen.mdb\network2_ND'
outNALayer = arcpy.na.MakeRouteLayer(network, "WorkRoute", "length")
outNALayer = outNALayer.getOutput(0)
subLayerNames = arcpy.na.GetNAClassNames(outNALayer)
points_layername = subLayerNames["Stops"]
routes_layername = subLayerNames["Routes"]

### add location, solve and export
input_point = r'C:\\Users\hyan1\Desktop\Route_2\T11_1_11_pro_lyr_1.shp'
output_name = os.path.split(input_point)[1]
arcpy.na.AddLocations(outNALayer, points_layername, input_point, "", "", "DateTimeS")
arcpy.na.Solve(outNALayer)
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("WorkRoute\Routes", r"C:\Users\hyan1\Desktop\Route_2\shortest_route", output_name)
```

'''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is actually documented on the [Error: 000824](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013100) page.

The solution is to

> Add the following code snippet to check-out the extension containing
> the tool before calling the tool for use:
>
> ```
>    import arcpy
>    …
>    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("[Extension name]")
> ```

The extension names are documented in the [`arcpy.CheckOutExtension`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/checkoutextension.htm) help. For Network Analyst use:

```
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Network")
```